# Страница вывода кастомных постов имеет странный title?

Tags: wordpress

Привет сделал для WP Custom Post Type. Вывод постов описал в archive-film.php ( Film названия Post Type ). Подгружаю стандартный header , которые в title имеет `<?php the_title(); ?>`
Но проблема. Ведь страница со всем постами не создана через админку WordPress. И таким образом title у меня выводится - название последнего поста. Такая же ситуация и с новостями, новости описал в index.php и title данной страницы - заголовок последней новости Кто знает как решить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `the_title()` выводит заголовок текущей записи. На архивной странице она, естественно, выведет заголов первой записи.

Для вывода заголовка страницы архивов есть другая функция - `the_archive_title()`.